# how can I update loopback.io to a newer version when I already have my code written?

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

I have an API server built with loopback.io (NodeJS) version 3.0.0, however latest version is 3.17.1 and there obviously have been a lot of security and bug fixes over all this time, which makes me feel on potential danger and outdated.

How can I update the framework without affecting my own code? How do other frameworks deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: Check the framework versions differences, update the framework, apply the differences in the versions and then solve the bugs or errors you may find in your own code.

Comment: You update your dependencies, like loopback.io, and then you run your tests and make sure you haven't had anything break.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be completely separate from the loopback.io code.  As such, you should be able to do `npm update looback.io` from the right directory and it should update the loopback.io code and not affect your code at all.

Now this assumes you were using loopback.io as a library that you loaded with `require()` and that you did not modify the actual loopback.io code yourself in any way.

Before upgrading, you will want to examine the release notes for the revisions of loopback.io since the version you originally installed and make sure there are only bug fixes and no compatibility issues with code written for prior versions (e.g. API changes, etc...).  If there are any API changes or "breaking" fixes, then you may have to slightly modify your code in that one area to update to the new API.

Then, after upgrading, run your unit tests to see if everything is still working as you would expect.